# jQuery issues on my page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I added jQuery via CDN to my page (no issue there) and I even got an alert function to work. I am playing around with different things like hide and toggle but they are not working. Here's my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div>
    <center>
      <h1>Lets have fun!<br>
    I want to learn a little more <br>
    Finally feeling like I understand again!</h1>
    </center>
    <center><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Click This</a>
    </center>
  </div>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      alert("This works");
      $("click this").hide(300)
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `$("click this")` won't work because neither `click` nor `this` are valid selectors (elements, IDs, classes, etc.). Well, `this` could be but not the way you're using it. Read https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/

Comment: So to get it to work use "btn btn-danger" ?

Comment: @Jhodges11 No, `btn` and `btn-danger` are not _element names_.

Comment: `$(".btn.btn-danger").click(function(){ $(this).hide(300) })`

Comment: and on a side note, please stop using `<center>`

Comment: You appear to be a beginner in web development. Here a few tips: don’t use `<center>`, it’s deprecated; instead use CSS to center elements. `<link>`s go into the `<head>` section (which should be above the `<body>`), along with the mandatory `<title>` element and the recommended `<meta charset="utf-8"/>`. A `$(document).ready` at the end of the body is pretty useless, since all the elements you need are already parsed. If you want a button, use `<input type="button" />`, not `<a href="#">`. Read the jQuery and JS documentation and end your statements with semicolons.

Comment: I am definitely a beginner some of the things I learned from tutorials but a friend pointed me to this site. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery you target element by using CSS selectors, such as CSS class selectors.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("This works");
        $('.btn.btn-danger').hide(300);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery to refer to a class name you begin it with a dot (`.`), an ID would begin with a hash (`#`), and element names are the exact element. Thus if you have an element like `<div id="mydiv" class="myclass"/>` you would refer to it as either `$('div')`, `$('#mydiv')` or `$('.myclass')`. You can also chain multiple selectors together, so `$('#myid.myclass')` would also be valid.

See the jQuery documentation on [Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for more info.

In your example you would use:

```
$(".btn.btn-danger").hide(300);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to hide the text when you click on the "Click This" button.  You need the following in your jQuery

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
      $('center').hide(300);
});
```

The above basically says when you click on the `<a>` element, hide the `<center>` element with a 300 millisecond animation.  Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/g83do40f/).

While the above will work, I strongly encourage you to assign either classes or an ID to your `<a>` and `<center>` elements.  Otherwise, as the page expands and you start adding more of the same elements, you'll start seeing unintended side effects of your jQuery bindings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change **$("click this")** to $(".btn") (or even $(".btn.btn-danger") ) as you have to (usually) use either classes and/or element ID's to target an element.  So ideally, your code would look like this:

```
    <a href="#" id="my_link" class="btn btn-danger">Click This</a>
```

In addition, you have to tell jQuery what event you want it to handle for an element.  If you don't tell it what event to use, then it will just act on that element when the page loads.

So add an id and change your code to this:

```
    $("#my_link").click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
```